# Implemention of Chess game

Tags: python

I'm storing all chess pieces on the board in a matrix.
Each cell is a chess piece(see below):

```
class ChessPiece:
    def __init__(self, color, row, col):
        self.color = color
        self.position = (row, col)
```

And all pieces inherits from the class above.
Also: (see below):

```
class Empty(ChessPiece):
    def __init__(self, row, col):
        super().__init__(-1, row, col)
```

I'm writing a function that checks if from point a to b there is a chess piece diagonally.
I have a little bug in this code (see below):

```
def is_piece_in_the_way_diagonal(x_src, x_dst, y_src, y_dst, board):
    x_direction = -1 if x_src < x_dst else 1
    y_direction = 1 if y_src < y_dst else -1

    x_src += x_direction
    y_src += y_direction

    while (x_src * x_direction <= x_dst * x_direction) and (
           y_src * y_direction <= y_dst * y_direction) and (
           0 <= x_src < 8) and (0 <= y_src < 8):
        square = board[x_src][y_src]
        if not isinstance(square, Empty):
            return True, square
        x_src += x_direction
        y_src += y_direction
    return False, Empty
```

This is a case the function does not work:

[image: Case]

The source square is (4, 7) # black queen
The destination square is (7, 4) # white king
The function returns `False` but should return `True` because there is a pawn in between the queen and the king.

Comment: "I have a little bug in this code" what do you mean by this? Are you getting an error? If so please [edit[ to include the full error traceback. Are you getting a wrong output? If so, please [edit[ to describe the current output and the expected output. This will help us to understand your issue better

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a runnable [mre] that reproduces the "little bug".

Answer (score 1):

This are several problems with your function which are why it doesn't work. Since you did not provide runnable sample code I created minimal scaffolding in order to have something to use for testing my answer to your question. It would have been better for you to have provided this…

The  problems I noticed in your `is_piece_in_the_way_diagonal()` function were:

1. The arguments to the function don't seem to be in the logical order.
2. The expressions defining the values of `x_direction` and `y_direction` in the function were inconsistent (and one was wrong).
3. The conditions controlling the `while` loop were overly complicated as well as incorrect — causing it to quit prematurely.

Here's sample code that I think show how to do what you desire:

```
class BoardState:
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


Empty = BoardState()
White_Pawn = BoardState('White_Pawn')
Black_Queen = BoardState('Black_Queen')
White_King = BoardState('White_King')

board = [[Empty for _ in range(8)] for _ in range(8)]
board[4][7] = Black_Queen
board[7][4] = White_King

def is_piece_in_the_way_diagonal(x_src, y_src, x_dst, y_dst, board):
    """ Checks diagonally if there is a chess piece between the source and
        destintation board positions and returns True and the piece if there is.
    """
    x_direction = 1 if x_src < x_dst else -1
    y_direction = 1 if y_src < y_dst else -1

    x_src += x_direction
    y_src += y_direction

    while ((0 <= x_src < 8) and (0 <= y_src < 8) and
           (x_src != x_dst) and (y_src != y_dst)):
        square = board[x_src][y_src]
        if square is not Empty:  # Something in the way?
            return True, square
        x_src += x_direction
        y_src += y_direction

    return False, None  # Nothing in way.


# Test function.
board[6][5] = White_Pawn  # Put a piece in the way.
result = is_piece_in_the_way_diagonal(4, 7, 7, 4, board)
assert result == (True, White_Pawn)

board[6][5] = Empty  # Remove piece.
result = is_piece_in_the_way_diagonal(4, 7, 7, 4, board)
assert result == (False, None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
x_direction = -1 if x_src < x_dst else 1
```

to

```
x_direction = 1 if x_src < x_dst else -1
```

As the queen approaches the king it should add a value of 1 as the king has the higher x_value.